# why I am getting error in this bellow code?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE bus_details
(
   bus_name         CHAR (15) PRIMARY KEY,
   total_seats      NUMBER (3),
   reserved_seats   NUMBER (3)
);

CREATE TABLE busreservation_status
(
   bus_name        CHAR (15) REFERENCES bus_details (bus_name),
   seat_id         NUMBER (3),
   reserved        CHAR (2) CHECK (reserved IN ('y', 'n')),
   customer_name   CHAR (15)
);
```

PL/SQL code:

```
DECLARE
   bname        CHAR (15);
   tot          NUMBER (3);
   resv         NUMBER (3);
   total_seats  NUMBER (3);

   CURSOR cur IS SELECT * FROM bus_details;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO bus_details
        VALUES ('&bus_name', total_seats, 0);

   OPEN cur;

   LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO bname, tot, resv;

      IF cur%FOUND
      THEN
         FOR i IN 1 .. tot
         LOOP
            INSERT INTO busreservation_status
                 VALUES (bname,
                         i,
                         'n',
                         NULL);
         END LOOP;
      ELSE
         EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cur;
END;
/
```

Error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Comment: Hi Mitali, what kind of error do you get actually?

Comment: In `insert into bus_details values('&bus_name',total_seats,0);` `total_seats` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL isn't supposed to be interactive with users. If you want to pass something to it, use a procedure with appropriate parameter(s).

If you rewrite code so that it looks like this

- note cursor FOR loop instead of explicitly declared cursor which requires opening, declaring cursor variables, fetching, exiting the loop, closing the cursor
- setting all required values for bus_details
- don't use `CHAR` datatype unless it makes sense. For e.g. bus name it doesn't, as that datatype right-pads value with spaces up to max column length

Then it *works*:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_bus_name        VARCHAR2 (15) := 'BMW';
  3     l_total_seats     NUMBER := 20;
  4     l_reserved_seats  NUMBER := 5;
  5  BEGIN
  6     INSERT INTO bus_details (bus_name, total_seats, reserved_seats)
  7          VALUES (l_bus_name, l_total_seats, l_reserved_seats);
  8
  9     FOR cur_r
 10        IN (SELECT bus_name, total_seats, reserved_seats FROM bus_details)
 11     LOOP
 12        FOR i IN 1 .. cur_r.total_seats
 13        LOOP
 14           INSERT INTO busreservation_status
 15                VALUES (cur_r.bus_name,
 16                        i,
 17                        'n',
 18                        NULL);
 19        END LOOP;
 20     END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result is:

```
SQL> select * From bus_details;

BUS_NAME        TOTAL_SEATS RESERVED_SEATS
--------------- ----------- --------------
BMW                      20              5

SQL> SELECT * FROM busreservation_status;

BUS_NAME           SEAT_ID RE CUSTOMER_NAME
--------------- ---------- -- ---------------
BMW                      1 n
BMW                      2 n
BMW                      3 n
BMW                      4 n
BMW                      5 n
<snip>
BMW                     19 n
BMW                     20 n

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: so i have to insert bus details first ?

Comment: Of course; otherwise, foreign key constraint will fail.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set some value to the variable **total_seats number(3);** or prompt input value for **total_seats** when inserting operation in process:

for example:

```
  Declare
   bname       Char(15);
   tot         Number(3);
   resv        Number(3);
   total_seats Number(3) := 15;

   Cursor cur Is
     Select * From bus_details;
 Begin
   Insert Into bus_details Values ('&bus_name', total_seats, 0);
   Open cur;
   Loop
     Fetch cur
       Into bname, tot, resv;
     If cur%Found Then
       For i In 1 .. tot Loop
         Insert Into busreservation_status Values (bname, i, 'n', Null);
       End Loop;
     Else
       Exit;
     End If;
   End Loop;
  Close cur;
 End;
 /

  OR

  Declare
   bname       Char(15);
   tot         Number(3);
   resv        Number(3);
   total_seats Number(3);

   Cursor cur Is
     Select * From bus_details;
 Begin
   Insert Into bus_details Values ('&bus_name', '&total_seats', 0);
   Open cur;
   Loop
     Fetch cur
       Into bname, tot, resv;
     If cur%Found Then
       For i In 1 .. tot Loop
         Insert Into busreservation_status Values (bname, i, 'n', Null);
       End Loop;
     Else
       Exit;
     End If;
   End Loop;
  Close cur;
 End;
 /
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need to insert bus_details first, the FK on busreservation_status to bus_details requires it. Further there are additional suggested changed.

1. Drop column reserved_seats from bus_details. This column is fully
   derivable from busreservation_status and typically maintaining a
   running count is just not worth the effort. But having it and not
   maintaining leads to data errors. For Example: you can have more
   seats reserved then the bus has seats.
2. Drop the column reserved from busreservation_status. This is
   derivable from customer_name; if customer_name is not null the seat
   is reserved. But assuming you "must keep it" then define is a
   virtual column bases on customer_name. This would keep the column in
   sync with there being a customer for the seat.
3. Change char columns to varchar2, and I would change number to
   integer.
   Create a procedure for setting up a bus (IMO better). The procedure
   can be parameterized, not an attempt at user interaction - which
   **plsql can not do anyway**. But whether you create a procedure or keep an anonymous block, there is no need for a loop; a single insert is all that is needed.

With the above in place we arrive at:

```
create table bus_details
(
    bus_name      varchar2 (15) primary key
  , total_seats   number (3)
);

create table busreservation_status
(
   bus_name        varchar2 (15)  references bus_details (bus_name)
 , seat_id         number (3) 
 , customer_name   varchar2 (15) 
 , reserved        varchar2 (1) generated always as  
                                ( case when customer_name is null then 'n' else 'y' end) virtual
 , constraint      busreservation_status_pk
                   primary key (bus_name,seat_id)
);


create or replace 
procedure  define_bus(bus_name_in bus_details.bus_name%type 
                     ,seats_in    bus_details.total_seats%type
                     ) 
is 
begin 
    insert into bus_details(bus_name, total_seats)
         values (bus_name_in, seats_in); 
    insert into busreservation_status(bus_name, seat_id) 
       select bus_name_in, level
         from dual connect by level <= seats_in; 
end ;
```

For quick look at the bus states at summary and detail level you can create views. The demo also includes a couple.